# How do I resize a btn-xl that has large font to fit properly on a small screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have the following in a Bootstrap 3 document:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-xl" href="#package-details">
            <span class="text-uppercase"><span class="text-white-dark">Pre-Order &amp; </span>Pledge Now</span>
        </a>
</div>
```

With 1 css rule override:

```
.btn-xl {
    font-size: 34px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

But on a small device it hangs off the screen. On the larger devices it looks fine.

How do I get this to be about 80% width (as opposed to the current 105%) on a small screen, without affecting the current size on the others?

In other words, what I want to happen is whenever a mobile device loads my site, I want the button to be big...but not overflowing off the page. It doesn't even have to be the same proportion as it is for larger screens via `col-md-*` and `col-lg-*`.

**Note that I don't want to use JS, just CSS.**

You can see it [live here](http://jsfiddle.net/5HHzg/)

Comment: you write a media query,that's all.

Comment: Can you show me an example of what that would look like - as in...specific to this example.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) { 
    h1 {
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .btn-xl {
        font-size: 22px;
        padding: 10px 16px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the h1 css? Also please mark the question as answered if it has been answered.